# back fill data on the condition that there is a 1 located <=2 rows previously to your current location

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{ 
    "group":          [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1], 
    "value":          [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,0, 0, 1, 1], 
    "desiredResult":  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,0, 0, 1, 1], 
 })
```

[image]

My goal here is to bfill() based on 2 conditions:

- **bfill()** only if **"group"** **has a 1**
- in **"value"**, bfill() only if there is a **1, two rows or less from the current location**

ex.

- values[2:5]  ==> we want to backfill the 1's in desiredResult[2:5],    since there is a 1 located two rows away from the current location    aka values[5]
- values[5:7]  ==> we want to backfill the 1's in desiredResult[5:7],      since there is a 1 located 1 row away from the    current location       aka values[7]
- values[11:14]  ==> we want to backfill the 1's in desiredResult[11:14], since there is a 1 located two rows away from      the current location aka values[14]
- values[17:20] ==> we want to backfill the 1's in desiredResult[17:20], since there is a 1 located two rows away from      the current location aka values[20]
- values [24:25] === nothing will occur here because the 1 is located about 3 rows away from values[24]

Comment: when you say `bfill` do you mean replace `0` by `1`? Can you have anything other than `0`/`1`? Should the `group` exclude only the values to fill or also the reference to find the `1`s?

Comment: when you say bfill do you mean replace 0 by 1?   ==>  that is correct.  I'm open to other methods if possible.  I just thought bfill() might be the easiest way

Comment: Can you have anything other than 0/1?   ===> In my current dataFrame I am just using 0's and 1's.  I'm not using anything else.

Comment: Should the group exclude only the values to fill or also the reference to find the 1s?  ===> i'm not to sure how to proplery answer this.  But all i'm looking for in the i'm just looking to run this bfill() operation only within that specific set of successive 1's.  all successive 1's in group are unique to that specific range of 1's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can form groups ending in `1` in `value`, check the group size with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and use this to replace the `0`s by `1`:

```
N = 2
g = df.loc[::-1, 'value'].eq(1).cumsum()
m1 = df.groupby(g).transform('size').le(N+1)
m2 = df['group'].eq(1) & df['value'].eq(0)

df.loc[m1&m2, 'value'] = 1
```

*NB. if you want a new column replace `df.loc[m1&m2, 'value'] = 1` by `df['out'] = df['value'].mask(m1&m2, 1)`.*

Output:

```
    group  value  desiredResult
0       0      0              0
1       1      1              1
2       1      1              1
3       1      1              1
4       1      1              1
5       1      1              1
6       1      1              1
7       1      1              1
8       0      0              0
9       0      0              0
10      0      0              0
11      1      1              1
12      1      1              1
13      1      1              1
14      1      1              1
15      0      0              0
16      0      0              0
17      1      1              1
18      1      1              1
19      1      1              1
20      1      1              1
21      1      0              0
22      1      0              0
23      1      0              0
24      1      1              1
25      1      1              1
```

Intermediates and output as new column:

```
    group  value  desiredResult   g     m1     m2  out
0       0      0              0  10   True  False    0
1       1      1              1  10   True  False    1
2       1      1              1   9   True  False    1
3       1      0              1   8   True   True    1
4       1      0              1   8   True   True    1
5       1      1              1   8   True  False    1
6       1      0              1   7   True   True    1
7       1      1              1   7   True  False    1
8       0      0              0   6  False  False    0
9       0      0              0   6  False  False    0
10      0      0              0   6  False  False    0
11      1      1              1   6  False  False    1
12      1      0              1   5   True   True    1
13      1      0              1   5   True   True    1
14      1      1              1   5   True  False    1
15      0      0              0   4   True  False    0
16      0      0              0   4   True  False    0
17      1      1              1   4   True  False    1
18      1      0              1   3   True   True    1
19      1      0              1   3   True   True    1
20      1      1              1   3   True  False    1
21      1      0              0   2  False   True    0
22      1      0              0   2  False   True    0
23      1      0              0   2  False   True    0
24      1      1              1   2  False  False    1
25      1      1              1   1   True  False    1
```

Comment: this is pretty close to what i'm looking for.  the only thing that it is not doing correctly is from values[20:24].  Nothing should occur there since the "1" located on values[24], the previous "1" located at value[20] is located 3 rows away.

Comment: @aaaahhhhhh there was a typo in my answer, `ge` (≥) should have been a `le` (≤) ;)